# How to communicate from the child component to parent attribute directive in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ckeditor

My goal is to let a custom directive listen for a DOM event inside its scope; and handle that event.  In this case, that DOMEvent will happen in a third-party component I do not control.

In Angular, I have the following template defined in a component.

This template has a directive (called `my-directive`) that is hooked into the keypress event for the ckeditor component.

I don't own the code for ckeditor; and am attempting to get away with not having to change any code so that this can be a reusable hook.

#### somecomponent.ts

```
<!-- lots of irrelevant template code snipped -->
<my-directive>
  <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" (keypress)="pressed($event)"></ckeditor>
</my-directive>
<!-- lots of irrelevant template code snipped -->
```

`my.directive.ts` has the following defined:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: 'my-directive',
  })
  export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
    public pressed(e: Event) : void {
        console.table(e);
    }

    constructor(
    ) { }
    ngOnInit() : void {
    }
}
```

And the CKEditor comes from the angular-ckeditor package; with the following imports where it's used:

`import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';`
`import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`

When I attempt to call the `pressed` function from the ckeditor tag; it complains that `pressed` is not a function:

```
exception-handler.ts:41 TypeError: _co.pressed is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SomeComponent.html:60)
    at handleEvent (core.js:21673)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:22767)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:22470)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:19122)
    at core.js:19569
    at HTMLUnknownElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422) "/myurl/1"
```

Perhaps the issue is that Angular is attempting to call `pressed()` on `ckeditor`?

So I tried to use a template reference variable:

```
<!-- lots of irrelevant template code snipped -->
<my-directive #md>
  <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" (keypress)="md.pressed($event)"></ckeditor>
</my-directive>
<!-- lots of irrelevant template code snipped -->
```

And so I got this error:

```
TypeError: jit_nodeValue_4(...).pressed is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SomeComponent.html:60)
    at handleEvent (core.js:21673)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:22767)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:22470)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:19122)
    at core.js:19569
    at HTMLUnknownElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422) "/myurl/1"
```

Bottom line, my question is this:

How do I allow a directive to respond to standard DOM events raised in a child component?

I do not want to modify child components; and in some cases I can't (it's not my code).  I am hoping this directive can be added to templates for other components and those components don't have to be modified internally to allow for the new behavior this directive implements.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation; it appears that listening to a standard DOM event by attaching to the child component's template declaration is overkill, and I can achieve what I want by doing the following:

1. Add a `@HostListener` to `MyDirective`:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: 'my-directive',
  })
  export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
    public pressed(e: Event) : void {

    }
    @HostListener('keypress') onKeyPress(e: Event) {
        console.table(e);
    }
    constructor(
    ) { }
    ngOnInit() : void {
    }
}
```

2. Modify the template to remove the declaration and simply keep the `my-directive` declaration wrapped around the child:

```
<!-- lots of irrelevant template code snipped -->
<my-directive>
  <ckeditor [editor]="Editor"></ckeditor>
</my-directive>
<!-- lots of irrelevant template code snipped -->
```

Now if any keypress event happens within the `my-directive` tag (whether it or its children), it'll raise an event that `@HostListener` will respond to.

Comment: I appreciated your self-Q&A. Wanted to note that *Native DOM Events always bubble unless squenched through `stop`[`Immediate`]`Propagation()`*. I believe you can simply wrap <ckeditor> with a <div (keypress)="handleWithAnyComponent($event)">. **You should test your <my-directive> to see if something like <ckeditor [my-directive]="handleEvent($event)"> in componation with @HostListener to see if there's a lighter-weight solution -- and then post your findings here!**